# usage of dissimilar

Tags: differences, formality, collocation, repetition

This sentence is grammatically correct. But does it make sense to use word *dissimilar* to avoid repetition of *different* here?

> the results would be absolutely dissimilar if there is any slight difference in the coefficients.

Writing type: formal

Comment: _dissimilar_ sounds unusual in this context, but I don't know if it's actually wrong. However, _if there is_ should be _if there were_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most writers on English style deprecate what is mockingly called "elegant variation", using synonyms purely in order to avoid repetition. Using different words suggests to a reader that two different concepts are involved, which is clearly not the case in your example. You make your point more strongly by using the same word with explicitly contrasted terms to emphasize the difference in degree:

> The results will be **significantly** different if there is **even an apparently insignificant** difference in the coefficients.